# What does this question about dense subsets mean?

Tags: general-topology

What does this question mean?

> Let  $(X,d)$ be a metric space. which of the following is possible?
>
> (A) $X$ has exactly $3$ dense subsets
> (B) $X$ has exactly $4$ dense subsets
> (C) $X$ has exactly $5$ dense subsets
> (D) $X$ has exactly $6$ dense subsets

Comment: It means exactly what it says. You must determine whether it is possible for a metric space to have exactly $3$ different dense subsets, exactly $4$ different dense subsets, exactly $5$ different dense subsets, or exactly $6$ different dense subsets. For instance, $\Bbb R$ with the usual metric has infinitely many different dense subsets, since $\Bbb R\setminus\{x\}$ is a dense subset of $\Bbb R$ for each $x\in\Bbb R$. On the other hand, $\Bbb N$ has only one dense subset, itself. However, There are metric spaces for which at least one of the four answers is true.

Comment: The mathematical question itself already has an answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1573573/no-of-possible-dense-subsets-of-a-metric-space), so I’m going to close this one, even though it’s technically a different question – you’re asking what the question means, not how to solve it. If you still have questions about the meaning and don’t want to see the answer yet, leave a comment for me here.